# Why on surface appeared line after using extrude

Tags: extrude

After I used extrude as you can see the surface appeared this lines, how can I solve this problem?

Thank you
[image]

Comment: Hello maybe a simple Auto Smooth will fix the problem, or could you please the object with the problem? https://blend-exchange.com/